# DateDiff to date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list in excel with the difference between today and the first day of the year, e.g today (April 4th, 2015) is number 95 (I calculate every year as a leap year because I have a calender which contains the 29th February. If the year is not a leap year I will hide the column.)

How can I get the date to the day number? (04.04.2015)
Is there a kind of formula?

Example:

```
Input    Output
-----    ------------
95       4 April 2015
96       5 April 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't *need* to calculate every year as a leap year. If you would like actual days from the first of the year, you could use: 
`=TODAY() - DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1) + 1` 
This will be correct regardless of leap year and will return an integer number of days if the cell is formatted as a number. For instance, today is actually the 94th day.

Second, to convert nth day to date, just do the reverse.  
`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1) + A1 - 1`
where A1 is a cell containing the nth day of the year and this formula is placed in a cell formatted as a Date.

To get the date from nth day of the year, assuming every year was a leap year use the following: 
`=DATEVALUE(TEXT(DATE(2004,1,A1),"MM/DD")&"/"&YEAR(TODAY()))`
This will throw an error on years where February 29 is not a valid date.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I dont need to use the leap year, but I have a calender which containts the 29th February. If the year is not a leap year I will hide the column.

Comment: Try the second formula on your day of the year cells to get dates.

Comment: Actually, in your case, try formula 3.

Comment: @ForJ9 Did this answer your question? Is there anything that needs changing or clarification? Please select my answer if it indeed answered the question. Thanks :)